# absolute value of norm of integral element

Tags: number-theory

consider $\mathbb{Q}\subset K$ a finite algebraic extension. Take $x\in K$ integral, why $\mid Norm_{K/\mathbb{Q}}(x)\mid \geq 1$?

Another question is: is it true that $\bar{\mathbb{Q}}_p \cong \mathbb{C}$? if it is so why?

Thank you.

Comment: Using Zorn's lemma and transcendence degrees, it can be shown that an algebraically closed field that is *uncountable* is determined up to isomorphism *as a field* by its cardinality and characteristic.  In particular, the alg. closure of Q_p has the same cardinality as the reals, as does C, and both fields are alg. closed with characteristic 0, so they are isomorphic. (The alg. closures of Q and Q(x) are both countable with characteristic 0 but are *not* isomorphic fields, so the uncountability condition is somewhat necessary.)

Comment: What is meant by $\bar{\mathbb{Q}}_p$? Algebraic closure?

Comment: Yes, the overline above the notation for a field is a standard notation for algebraic closure of that field.

Comment: yes, it is algebraic closure

Answer (score 1):

The norm of an integer is a rational integer.

<strike>$\mathbb Q_p$ cannot be extended to $\mathbb C$ because it has a different metric.</strike>

Comment: Your second sentence is wrong: ukn is asking about the algebraic closure of Q_p and that field *is* isomorphic to the complex numbers.

Comment: @KCd, isomorphic as a field but not as a metric space?

Comment: The p-adic abs. value on the rational numbers can be extended to the complex numbers using Zorn's lemma (but it is completely nonconstructive) and Q_p can be embedded into C by Zorn's lemma.

Comment: Of course they are not isomorphic as metric spaces (one is connected in the induced metric topology and the other is not) but I suspect ukn is asking about an isomorphism as fields, not as metrized fields.  In any case, it is definitely worthwhile coming to grips with the fact that the alg. closure of Q_p *is* isomorphic to C as abstract fields.

Comment: To expand a little on quanta's answer. $x\in K$ integral means $x$ is a root of a monic polynomial with integer coefficients. Its norm is the product of its conjugates, which is (up to sign) the constant term of said monic polynomial.